# What is a atomic write unit for mordern SSDs?

Tags: storage, atomic, disk, solid-state-drive

My understanding is that a most modern spindle based drives have a "sector" as an atomic write unit. What is the unit for modern ssds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by atomic write unit. I am assuming you mean the smallest unit of write.

In a NAND-flash SSD, the smallest unit of read and write is called a page. Typically, page size would be 2kB or 4kB, plus metadata.

Also, the smallest unit of erase is a few pages (32-128 pages).

Sources:

http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NAND_memories

Answer (score 1):

There are pages and blocks inside SSDs. I recommend [Coding for SSDs](https://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/). And there is the sector size of the transfer protocol. The transfer protocol is used for communication between the CPU and the SSD. It could be ATA, SCSI, NVMe, USB MS, ... The OS and all programs normally only know the sector size of the transfer protocol.

So here are some **example** values:

- page size 4kb
- block size 512kb (always a multiple of the page size)
- protocol sector size 512 bytes

Now when you write to an SSD directly (without having a file system) nobody guarantees you that anything is atomic. Even if you write a single byte perhaps during the program phase if there is a power failure it's not atomic.

The transfer protocol (like NVMe) could provide atomicity but unfortunately in reality it's [not supported](https://lwn.net/Articles/789600/).

As a normal programmer you can use a database like SQLite or MySQL which provide atomicity as part of [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). You don't have to worry about anythingy. But make sure transactions are enabled and autocommit is off.

If you're writing a database yourself you have to rely on functions like [fsync](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) and the [file system journaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling-Dateisystem).

If you're writing to an SSD directly and you know the block size here is an example how you can get atomicity (I am doing this in reality on an Arduino):

- one block stores a bool only (0 or 1) which toggles between data area 0 and 1
- N blocks hold all the data you want to store (data area 0)
- N blocks also hold all the data you want to store (data area 1)

Now let's assume you have already written data to data area 0 and also the bool is 0. But you want to update the data. What you do is write all data to data area 1 and at the end you toggle the bool to 1. When you want to write again you write everything to data area 0 and toggle the bool again. This way you can do atomic writes. Don't forget to call sync, commit or flush (if available) after writing a data area or the bool.

Of course this algorithm can be improoved by adding checksums to the data areas or implementing journaling.